# SSH refused after updating from wheezy to jessie

Tags: debian, ssh

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B and I updated it this afternoon from wheezy to jessie. I connect headlessly with VNC and SSH (usually the latter) because I play around with home LAMP and nodeJS servers.

Both worked fine before the upgrade. Since upgrading to jessie, SSH has been refusing my connections. The error is:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.3 port 22: Connection refused
```

So, I double checked the IP - no problem there. Then, I checked the hostname and users, both are correct. Then, I tried clearing my RSA keys on both the Mac and the Pi. No luck.

Finally, I checked to make sure the SSH daemon was actually running. And, it wasn't. So, I went through `raspi-config` and started SSH. I checked again with service ssh status and still got an empty response.

So, my question is: **why isn't the SSH service starting and could it have something to do with updating to jessie?**

If so, is my only option to reflash with wheezy?

Comment: Jessie uses systemd. Services in `/etc/init.d/` *should* start at boot, but it might be worth running `systemctl enable sshd && systemctl start sshd`...

Comment: Look at your logs (/var/log/messages, possibly /var/log/secure or /var/log/sshd/something) to see why the service isn't starting. Without that info, no-one can help you.

Comment: People have been having problems left and right with systemd in ARM. I have been using Jessie *without* systemd.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is valid and service should listen on port 22. Then check iptables rules:

```
iptables -L -nvx
```

(Eventually `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` if you're chrooted into the system).

You can check `/var/log/auth.log` for messages like:

```
error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

which might mean that some keys are missing, check with:

```
ls -al /etc/ssh/ssh*key
```

Easiest way how to fix this would be:

```
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Jessie uses sort of hybrid mode for running services, there should be `/etc/init.d/ssh` script and also systemd config. Systemd `ssh` service should be enabled:

```
systemctl is-enabled ssh
```

in case that it's not, enable with `systemctl enable ssh`.

Make sure that `/var/run/sshd` directory exists:

```
/bin/mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/sshd
```

And finally you can try running `sshd` in debug mode:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config -d
```